# Add a angle to CAGradientLayer OSX cocoaTouch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa-touch

How can I add a angle (rotate) my CAGradientLayer?  Without rotating my view (self.colorView).  I just want to add a angle to the gradient
I create my CAGradientLayer like below

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[NSColor blueColor] CGColor], (id)[self.gradColorTwo CGColor], nil];
gradient.frame = self.colorView.bounds;
[self.colorView setLayer:gradient];
[self.colorView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `startPoint` and `endPoint`, without changing them you are using default (0.5,0.0) e (0.5,1.0) coordinates.
To make a 45° gradient change them into (0.0,0.0) and (1.0,1.0).